# Can't get 201 status for post request

Tags: reactjs

The code bellow is fetching data from my API. In the same time, when I click on `find button`, I should get in console the response status `201`, but I didn't get it, and the list of users is always identical on every post request. is it a problem in my fetch?

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Data = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    const [firstname, changeFirstname] = useState('');
    const [lastname, changeLastname] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8010/proxy');
            const myJson = await response.json();
            console.log(myJson);
            setState(myJson)
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    function changeFirstName(e) {
        changeFirstname(e.target.value)
    }

    function changeLastName(e) {
        changeLastname(e.target.value)
    }

    function saveVal() {
        console.log(firstname + " " + lastname);
        fetch('http://localhost:8010/proxy', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, body: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname
            })
        }).then(response => response).then(data => console.log(data))
    }



    return (
        <div>
            <div className="fetch">
                <ul>
                    {state.map(i => <li>{i.firstName + i.lastName}</li>)}
                </ul>
                <input onChange={changeFirstName} type="text" placeholder='add your name'/>
                <input onChange={changeLastName} type="text" placeholder='add your last-name'/>
                <button onClick={saveVal}>find</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Data;
```

[image]

Comment: How does your backend look like? Where are you handling this request?

Comment: @tudor.gergely as backend I used nodejs and i made an api. The api is working.